# Reserve CPU and Memory for Linux Host in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running several docker containers via docker-compose on a server.

Problem is, that the load of the containers for some reason always crashes my server after a while...

I can only find resources and answered questions on how to limit a containers cpu/memory usage, but what I want to achieve is giving all containers in total let's say a CPU or Memory usage of like 85% and reserve the rest for the Linux Host so that the server itself doesn't crash.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: This question isn't really specific to Kafka...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `docker-machine`, I guess... Then you would define a VM within which all containers would run, and you limit the VM's total memory, leaving the rest for the host.

Otherwise, Docker is running as a native process on the machine, and there isn't a way to place a total limit on "all Docker processes"

Comment: Would there be any significant downsides of using docker-machine? for example stability or performance?

Comment: It starts a VM rather than being a native process, so there will be some performance degradation, but it is the only way I'm aware of to give yourself that "sandbox" limitation of where/how Docker processes are running.

Answer (score 1):

The best idea I have right now is to set the cpu limit of each service/container so that sum never reaches 85% but in the long run you should investigate why the server crashes. Maybe it is a cooling or PSU issue?